# Errors when using rmarkdown::render to create reproducible pdfs reports, but does when knitting

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, rgb, pandoc

I created a reproducible report that knits but won't reproduce when using rmarkdown::render due to two different errors that I can't seem to figure it out. My main issues are around using ggplot2 and xcolor colors using rgb when creating tables with kable to "latex". My client requested particular colors which made this whole, not so well paid, experience difficult. Below are the error messages.

**error related to ggplot:**

```
Quitting from lines 222-233 (Grantee_Report.Rmd)
Error in dir.create(dirname(name), recursive = TRUE) :
invalid 'path' argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (!grepl("[.]html$", output_file)) knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.retina = NULL) :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: Column Qi joining factor and character vector, coercing into character vector
3: In matrix(0:6, nrow = 1, ncol = 6) :
data length [7] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of columns [6]
4: In if (!file_test("-d", dirname(name))) dir.create(dirname(name), :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

**Error related to colors (where I used RGB):**

```
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 2
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (!grepl("[.]html$", output_file)) knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.retina = NULL) :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: Column Qi joining factor and character vector, coercing into character vector
3: In if (nzchar(file_ext)) paste(".", file_ext, sep = "") else "" :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

**Here is an abbreviated version of the report and related dataset.**

```
data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
            CenterID = c(4763L, 4762L, 5441L, 4722L, 4726L),
             GrantID = c("Grantee ID 4544", "Grantee ID 4544",
                         "Grantee ID 5141", "Grantee ID 4540",
                         "Grantee ID 4540"),
           MonitorID = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 3L),
              Qi1_SA = c(3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L),
                 Qi1 = c(4, 5, 5, 4, 5),
              Qi2_SA = c(3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L),
                 Qi2 = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5),
              Qi3_SA = c(3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L),
                 Qi3 = c(5, 5, 5, 4, 1),
              Qi4_SA = c(3, 5, 2, 3, 3),
                 Qi4 = c(0, 4, 1, 3, 3),
              Qi5_SA = c(3, 5, 3, 3, 3),
                 Qi5 = c(0, 5, 3, 5, 5),
              Qi6_SA = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L),
                 Qi6 = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 3),
              Qi7_SA = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L),
                 Qi7 = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5),
             Qi11_SA = c(3, 5, 4, 5, 4),
                Qi11 = c(2, 5, 3, 5, 4),
             Qi12_SA = c(3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L),
                Qi12 = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5),
             Qi13_SA = c(3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L),
                Qi13 = c(0, 5, 2, 5, 4),
             Qi14_SA = c(3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L),
                Qi14 = c(5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L),
             Qi17_SA = c(3, 4, 5, 5, 3),
                Qi17 = c(4, 5, 5, 5, 3))
```

---

title: "Program Monitoring"
author: "Center-Level Report"
date: "Fall 2019"
header-includes:
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{array}
- \usepackage{multirow}
- \usepackage{wrapfig}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{colortbl}
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \usepackage{tabu}
- \usepackage{threeparttable}
- \usepackage{threeparttablex}
- \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
- \usepackage{makecell}
- \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
- \definecolor{othergreen}{RGB}{32, 176, 75}
output:

### pdf_document

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
options(kableExtra.latex.load_packages = FALSE)
#source("ACE_clean_data.R")
load("fall_ace_center.Rdata")

library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(reshape2)
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)
library(condformat)

# Practice Code for Center
# a subset of the original data is created, the rest of the report is based on this subset
fall_ace_sub <- 
  fall_ace_center %>% 
  dplyr::filter(CenterID == CID) #Replace wth CenterID placeholder for Center Level Report

# Objects for points of reference. 
#CenterID <- fall_ace_sub$CenterID
MS <- c("Qi1", "Qi2", "Qi3", "Qi4", "Qi5", "Qi6", "Qi7", "Qi11", "Qi12", "Qi13", "Qi14", "Qi17")
SA <- c("Qi1_SA", "Qi2_SA", "Qi3_SA", "Qi4_SA", "Qi5_SA", "Qi6_SA", "Qi7_SA", "Qi11_SA", "Qi12_SA", "Qi13_SA", "Qi14_SA", "Qi17_SA")
CC_cat1 <- c("Qi1", "Qi2", "Qi3", "Qi4", "Qi5", "Qi6", "Qi7", "Qi1_SA", "Qi2_SA", "Qi3_SA", "Qi4_SA", "Qi5_SA", "Qi6_SA", "Qi7_SA")

#Create subset of dataset to develop tables for figures and tables. 
fall_ace_ctrF <- 
  fall_ace_sub %>%
  dplyr::select(Qi1:Qi17, Qi1_SA:Qi17_SA)%>%
  t()

fall_ace_ctr1 <- data.frame(rownames_to_column(as.data.frame(fall_ace_ctrF, var = "Qi")))

fall_ace_ctr_fig <- 
  fall_ace_ctr1 %>%
    mutate(score_type = ifelse(rowname %in% MS, "Monitor Score", "Self-Assessment Score"),
           CCcat = ifelse(rowname %in% CC_cat1, "cat1", "cat2"),
           rowname = recode(rowname,
                          "Qi1_SA" = "Qi1", 
                          "Qi2_SA" = "Qi2",
                          "Qi3_SA" = "Qi3",
                          "Qi4_SA" = "Qi4",
                          "Qi5_SA" = "Qi5",
                          "Qi6_SA" = "Qi6",
                          "Qi7_SA" = "Qi7",
                          "Qi11_SA" = "Qi11",
                          "Qi12_SA" = "Qi12",
                          "Qi13_SA" = "Qi13",
                          "Qi14_SA" = "Qi14",
                          "Qi17_SA" = "Qi17"))

names(fall_ace_ctr_fig) <- c("Qi", "score", "score_type", "CCcat")

fall_ace_ctr_fig1 <- 
  fall_ace_ctr_fig %>%
  mutate(Qi =factor(Qi, c("Qi1", "Qi2", "Qi3", "Qi4", "Qi5", "Qi6", "Qi7", "Qi11", "Qi12", "Qi13", "Qi14", "Qi17")), 
         score_type = factor(score_type, levels = c("Self-Assessment Score", "Monitor Score")))

fall_ace_sub1a <- 
  fall_ace_sub %>%
  dplyr::select("Qi1", "Qi2", "Qi3", "Qi4", "Qi5", "Qi6", "Qi7", "Qi11", "Qi12", "Qi13", "Qi14", "Qi17")%>%
  t()

fall_ace_sub1 <- data.frame(rownames_to_column(as.data.frame(fall_ace_sub1a, var = "Qi")))

names(fall_ace_sub1) <- c("Qi", "Monitor Score")

fall_ace_sub2a <- 
  fall_ace_sub %>%
  dplyr::select("Qi1_SA", "Qi2_SA", "Qi3_SA", "Qi4_SA", "Qi5_SA", "Qi6_SA", "Qi7_SA", "Qi11_SA", "Qi12_SA", "Qi13_SA", "Qi14_SA", "Qi17_SA")

names(fall_ace_sub2a) <- c("Qi1", "Qi2", "Qi3", "Qi4", "Qi5", "Qi6", "Qi7", "Qi11", "Qi12", "Qi13", "Qi14", "Qi17")

fall_ace_sub2 <- data.frame(rownames_to_column(as.data.frame(t(fall_ace_sub2a), var = "Qi")))

names(fall_ace_sub2) <- c("Qi", "Self-Assessment Score")

fall_ace_ctr_tbl <- dplyr::right_join(fall_ace_sub2, fall_ace_sub1, by = "Qi")

cc_table_fall_full <- read.csv("CC_QI_Text_table.csv")

cc_table_fall <- select(cc_table_fall_full, -Qi)

names(cc_table_fall) <- gsub("\\.", " ", names(cc_table_fall))

cc_table_fall_short <- read.csv("CC_QI_Text_table_short.csv")

cc_table_fall_cc <- select(cc_table_fall_short, -Qi)

names(cc_table_fall_cc) <- gsub("\\.", " ", names(cc_table_fall_cc))

cc_table_spring <- read.csv("Spring_ACE_CC_Table.csv")

names(cc_table_spring) <- gsub("\\.", " ", names(cc_table_spring))

fall_ace_ctr_tbl1 <- right_join(cc_table_fall_short, fall_ace_ctr_tbl, by = "Qi")

fall_ace_ctr_tbl1 <- select (fall_ace_ctr_tbl1, -Qi)
```

TEXT

```
cc_table_fall%>%
  kable(align = c("l", "l"), format = "latex") %>%
  kable_styling("bordered") %>%
  row_spec(0, background = "othergreen", bold = TRUE, align = "c")%>%
  column_spec(1, border_left = TRUE)%>%
  column_spec(2, border_right = TRUE)%>%
  collapse_rows(columns = 1, valign = "top")
```

### This GGPlot causes the dir.name error - if removed, then the HTML color error occurs

```
fall_ace_ctr_fig1%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Qi, y = score, group = score_type, color = score_type))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 3, linetype = "dashed", color = "black") + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", strip.text = element_text(color = "black")) + 
  labs(linetype = "", color = "", shape = "", x = "Quality Indiators", y = "Scores", title = "Center Qi Indicators Scores - Fall 2019")+
  ylim(0,5)
```

```
fall_ace_ctr_tbl1%>%
  rename(`Compliance Component` = Compliance.Component,
         `Quality Indicator`= Quality.Indicators) %>%
  kable(align = c("c", "l", "c", "c"), format = "latex") %>%
    kable_styling("bordered") %>%
  row_spec(0, background = "othergreen", bold = TRUE)%>%
  column_spec(1, width = "6em", border_left = TRUE)%>%
  column_spec(3, width = "5em")%>%
  column_spec(4, border_right = TRUE, width = "5em")%>%
  collapse_rows(columns = 1, valign = "top")
```

## Spring 2019

```
cc_table_spring%>%
  kable(align = c("l", "l", "l"), format = "latex") %>%
  kable_styling("bordered") %>%
  row_spec(0, background = "othergreen", bold = TRUE, align = "c")%>%
  column_spec(1, width = "12em", border_left = TRUE)%>%
  column_spec(2, width = "12em")%>%
  column_spec(3, width = "12em", border_right = TRUE)%>%
  collapse_rows(columns = 1, valign = "top")
```

**And this is the report driver:**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(reshape2)

rm(list = ls())

#source(file = "ACE_clean_data.R")

load("fall_ace_center.Rdata")

# For Center Reports #
for (CID in unique(fall_ace_center$CenterID)){
      rmarkdown::render(input = paste(getwd(), "/Center_Report.Rmd", sep = ""),
                        output_format = "pdf_document",
                        output_file = paste(fall_ace_center$CenterID, "-", fall_ace_center$CenterName, " - Fall-2019.pdf", sep=""),
                        output_dir = paste(getwd(),"/Reports/", fall_ace_center$GranteeID, sep = ""))
  }
```

Comment: It looks like in your `render()` call, lines like `output_file = paste(fall_ace_center$CenterID, ...` will mean a vector of multiple filenames will be passed to `output_file`. As far as I know you can only pass a single output file, so you'll have to filter based on the current ID `CID`.

Comment: Thanks, Marius. That was helpful. I was able to get it running as long as I deleted the output_dir, following this https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1033) suggestion. It makes it annoying to organize files after the fact, but much less annoying then running 152 reports one at a time.

Comment: @MelissaR and @Marius  What might be another source of this error?  I removed my `output_dir` argument but still get the `invalid path` error when I try to render a ggplot.

Comment: For future reference: the same error occurs when setting `knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.path=<>)` to a vector instead of a single value.